# Transferring Thunderbird Data from Ubuntu to MacOS?

Tags: macos, email, firefox

On ubuntu all the thunderbird files are stored under `~/.thunderbird/`.  If I want to backup / copy the files to another Ubuntu laptop I can just copy that folder to the new laptop.

Is it the same for MacOS?

Can I just copy the `~/.thunderbird` folder to `~`?